# Physical Back Button handling in Template 10

Tags: winrt-xaml, template10

Template 10 Universal app works great on desktop PC but when I tried running it on Windows Phone pressing physical back button doesn't do what I want (for example navigate in my app, same behavior as back button on XAML page).

Is there good way to bind physical Windows phone button to XAML component like button?

Before I was doing it in code behind using:

```
if(Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent(Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons))
{
HardwareButons.BackPressed += OnBackPressed;
}
```

Then do the navigation in `OnBackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)`.

if I wanted default behavior

```
 e.Handled = false;
```

or custom

```
e.Handled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationService.FrameFacade.BackRequested` is an event located in the `FrameFacade` internal class, believe that is what you might be looking for.  It automatically looks for the hardware button contract, in the implementation, there does appear to be a bug that is being investigated at present with current version.